# React Material UI Range Slider value handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui

I have a range slider from material-UI. On the main page, the data table is rendered. The table has the following fields:

`id, name, current price, new price`.

The value of the `current price` for each of the items is fixed to some value. The value for the `new price` for the item will be determined on slider's value. As one of the handles (of the particular item of the table) of the range slider (suppose right one) is changed to some value, its' updated value will be added to the `current price` and that sum will be the value for `new price` for that particular item. i.e.

`item's new price = item's current price + item's slider value received`.

But the issue I am facing with the range slider is that it does not have any id property or attribute to match the handlers whose value is changed. Because of this, as the slider's value of any single item is changed, it adds to all of the items `current price` fields not the particular one selected.

For now, I am using hardcoded id check like:

```
if (ele.id === 2) {
        returnValue.new_price = ele.current_price + value;
      }
```

but I need to have a generic solution.

Working snippet link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-framework-rxui2?file=/src/App.js:822-908

Any help to resolve this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App.js, provide each `<RangeSlider />` an id prop, which you have from the table row data:

```
<RangeSlider id={data.id} setrange={fetchValue} range={range} />
```

In RangeSlider.js, make sure to send that id to `props.setrange` callback:

```
props.setrange(e.target.textContent, props.id);
```

Also don't forget to get the id argument in the function decleration (App.js):

```
const fetchValue = (value, id) => {
   ...
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was quite close. Can you help with one more thing in this? Is there a way to disable a particular range button, either left or right?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve that with the default Slider Thumb. You can provide your custom Thumb component,  where it's probably possible. You can see example of custom Thumb component [here](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/), under "Customized sliders"